# How to use a list of equations made with Table to plot with ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have created a list of equations with the following code:

[image]

Now if I try to plot them with ContourPlot by copying and pasting the output of A, I get:

[image]

Which is to be expected. Now If I do:

[image]

It doesn't work but I obtained a weird output using PlotLegends:

[image]

Ie: It takes each equation and writes $eq_i=7=0$ Why does this happens? Noticing this behavior, I tried to do the following:

[image]

But the equations in the PlotLegends got messier. So how can I use the list of equations A directly?

Comment: Add `Evaluate` maybe helpfull.

Comment: @cvgmt It worked, thanks! But why? If I use Head[] in `Evaluate[Table[Cos[y] x^2 + Sin[y] y^2 == 7 - n, {n, 1, 10, g}]]` it says "list", if I use Head[] in `Table[Cos[y] x^2 + Sin[y] y^2 == 7 - n, {n, 1, 10, g}]`, it also says "list".